# Drupal: Not able to enable 'anchor' and 'imce' buttons for 'admin' role in ckeditor

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have two roles 'site-admin' (super user) & 'admin' (can do limited stuff). When I login as 'site-admin', I am able to see 'anchor' and 'imce' buttons on ckeditor. (https://drupal.org/files/issues/site_admin_has_imce_button.png) When I login as 'admin', I cannot see it. (https://drupal.org/files/issues/admin_no_imce_button.png)

I enabled the 'strike-through' button, both 'site-admin' & 'admin' can see it.

Config:

- CKEditor 3.6.6.1.7696
- Wysiwyg 7.x-2.x
- IMCE: 7.x-1.9

Sorry, I post here as well (https://drupal.org/node/2272261)

**Update**:

I include the settings here

Profile setting
[image]

imce setting
[image]

**Solution**:
It turns out hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter is the issue. Once I fix 'hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter', everything is fine. I know hook can cause problems, but I never think about it in this case. (I don't know what I don't know.)

Answer (score 0):

Though this may not answer your question.. I recommend using [CKEditor](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module instead of WYSIWYG. It has a lot more configs and really works great.

But if you do not want to try that...

Have you checked permissions?

Also check in IMCE configurations at **/admin/config/media/imce**. I'm pretty sure this will at least help you to enable the imce button. I've ran in to this problem before.

Comment: The IMCE button should be showing for admin with the settings you show. I use ckeditor module and have never really had problems with it. Plus it's made for the library.

Comment: have you checked the site permissions? make sure they have the right to use the input format.